# Exchange server email logs location

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Recently we did not get some emails, from a specific provider. It seems the mails reach our server (there is no error on the sender side), so I want to check the logs why our Exchange server not process those emails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try something like this from the Exchange Management shell (or another machine with the Exchange cmdlets):

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -start '[date it started]' -resultsize unlimited | where-object {$_.Sender -like '*theirdomain.com'}
```

If that turns up a bunch of FAIL, try:

```
Get-AgentLog -startdate '[date it started]' | where {$_.P1FromAddress -like '*theirdomain.com'} | select-object Reason  | group-object Reason
```

for an explanation of why Exchange doesn't love them.  Silent drops are frequently antispam.

If there's no record of them ever touching Exchange, I'd assume that something is wrong on their end.

Comment: I just don't see anything, maybe the error is elsewhere. I marked this as answer.

Answer (score 4):

From the `Exchange Management Console`, in the `toolbox` menu, you can use the `Message Tacking` feature (this will open the GUI in the web interface).

**Edit :** To open the GUI whithin the Exchange Management Console, select `Mail Flow Troubleshooter`

From here you can define many filters to search for specific emails, and see how your transport servers have processed them.

http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-message-tracking/

Also, if you have an Anti-spam software/hardware appliance in front of your Exchange servers, it could be useful to check them to see if they have not considered these emails as Spam and dropped/quarantine them.

Comment: Hmm I just could not start the Message Tracking. It throw me an "Message tracking is currently unavailable" error message. I try to fix it as writed here: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/enterprise-software/67202-fix-exchange-2010-message-tracking-currently-unavailable-rbac.html , it works but after that when I clicking on the message tracking icon, it brings up the web interface of the Outlook WebApp? I was not sure this is what I looking for.

Comment: @NoNameProvided `Message Tracking` opens the tool in the Web Interface but **this is not OWA**, it is **ecp** (Exchange Control Panel) ! To get the same outside the Web Interface (mean inside Exchange Management Console) use `Mail Flow Troubleshooter` just above the Message tracking feature. I have updated my post in case it could help someone else. Basically, `Get-MessageTrackingLog` do the same thing, except that one is a powershell cmdlet while the other is GUI.